# How do I fix this issue about this array who change?

Tags: fortran90

I wanted to test Taylor's method and I have some problem. I don't know why but when I try to print the first line of x, the program print: 3.30448736E+17. But I don't see how it happen.

Thanks for help

```
    implicit none
    real,parameter :: x1=1,y1=2,h=0.5
    real,dimension(1:20) :: x,y
    integer :: n

    n=1
    x(1)= x1
    y(1)= y1

    do while(n<21)
            y(n+1)= y(n)+h*x(n)*y(n)+0.5*y(n)*(1+x(n)**2)*h**2                   
            x(n+1)=x(n)+h
        n=n+1
    end do

    print*,x(1)
```

Comment: Your loop illegally writes to x(21),  thereby corrupting the value of x(1). To fix, change the while statement to `do while(n<20)`

Comment: Incidentally,  it would be better practice here to use a straight do-loop, e.g.,`do n=2,20` rather than use a while loop, since you have a known number of loops to perform. It's easier to see what it's doing and therefore easier to debug.  Only use `do while`when the required number of loops is unknown at compile-time.

Comment: Oh ok tanks for your help and advice.